# How to find if a TreeNode has children

Tags: java, tree, smartgwt, treenode

I was using the 
`com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Tree` widget where for a selected`TreeItem` I could easily check if it has any children:

```
Tree nodesTree = new Tree();
nodesTree.getSelectedItem().getChildCount()
```

Now I wanted to use the 
`com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tree.Tree` widget but I do not know how to find if a selected `TreeNode` has any children. I'm a little confused on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google says it's `hasChildren(TreeNode node)`, which returns a boolean. See [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/tree/Tree.html#hasChildren%28com.smartgwt.client.widgets.tree.TreeNode%29).

EDIT: This checks if the node has any children (obviously). If you want to actually get the children, see Aaron's answer below. `getChildren(TreeNode node)` returns an array of tree nodes. So if you wanted to see how many children it has, perhaps use `getChildren(TreeNode node)` to get the array of children and then get the size of the array.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick answers.  I wanted the hasChildren(TreeNode node) method because actually I want to delete the node just in case it has no childs. I was thinking first of having something similar as in gwt Tree widget - the node to have actually an option to see if has any childs (getChildCount() ) - that's way I do not thought that the SmartGWT tree himself to have this methods you both said here. I think is late for me (0:38) so better to go to bed:D. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use...

```
getChildren(TreeNode node)
```

As viewed in the [source](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/source/browse/trunk/main/src/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/tree/Tree.java?spec=svn742&r=742#123)